# Opencart 3.x: Change manual invoice in adm let disabled products to be added

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-3

hello i nee dto customize my opencart manual invoice in admin.
id like to add disbaled products and enabled to my invoice. but only admin in administration can make it.

i tried to change this file:

```
system/library/cart/cart.php and in line 41
```

i replaced the line 41 query to

```
if (isset($this->session->data['api_id'])) {
$product_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_store p2s LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product p ON (p2s.product_id = p.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) WHERE p2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "' AND p2s.product_id = '" . (int)$cart['product_id'] . "' AND pd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "'");
} else {
$product_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_store p2s LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product p ON (p2s.product_id = p.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) WHERE p2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "' AND p2s.product_id = '" . (int)$cart['product_id'] . "' AND pd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND p.status = '1'");
}
```

but its keepeing blocking me to add disabled products on admin manual invoice cart.

Answer (score 0):

To check if admin is logged in use condition

```
if (isset($this->session->data['user_id']) && !empty($this->session- >data['user_token'])) {
// admin sql 
}else{
// stock sql
}
```

Comment: so, just replace `if (isset($this->session->data['api_id'])) {` for `if($this->session->data['user_id']){` ?

Comment: yes, in oc 3 admin session variable for id is user_id, i am editing code to check if admin is logged in else it might throw undefined index user_id